# Clustered Bar Plot Using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image: Snapshot of my data frame]

Basically I want to display a barplot which is grouped by Methods i.e I want to display the number of people conducted the tests, the number of positive test results had found for each of the methods. Also, I want to display all the numbers and percentages as labels on the bar. I am trying to display these using ggplot2. But I am failing every time.

Any helps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to have fully understand your question. But I will suggest you to take look on `geom_text`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = methods, y = percentage)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percentage,2), " (",positive," / ", people,")")), vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5)+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("NS1", "NS1+IgM", "NS1+IgG","Tourniquet")) + 
  ylim(0,100)
```

[image]

***Data:***

```r
df = data.frame(methods = c("NS1", "NS1+IgM","NS1+IgG","Tourniquet"),
                people = c(542,542,541,250),
                positive = c(505,503,38,93))
df$percentage = df$positive / df$people * 100

> df
     methods people positive percentage
1        NS1    542      505   93.17343
2    NS1+IgM    542      503   92.80443
3    NS1+IgG    541       38    7.02403
4 Tourniquet    250       93   37.20000
```

Does it answer your question ? If not, can you clarify your question by adding the code you have tried so far in `ggplot` ?

Comment: Yes it does answer my question. I was using the following codes.

>library(ggplot2)
>library(reshape2)
>df=data.frame(Methods=c('NS1', 'NS1+IgM', 'NS1+IgG', 'Tourniquet Test'), Positive=c(505,503,38, 93), Percent=c(93.2, 92.8,7.0,37.2))
>mm= melt(df, id.vars='Methods')
>q=ggplot(mm, aes(x=Methods, y=value))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+facet_grid(.~variable)+coord_flip()+labs(x='', y='')

Thank you so much.